# Python macro to process multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, macros

I am trying to automate the following code for columns ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD,...ColumnZ

```
ColumnA=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnA.max().reset_index()
ColumnB=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnB.max().reset_index()
ColumnC=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnC.max().reset_index()
ColumnD=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnD.max().reset_index()
ColumnE=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnE.max().reset_index()
ColumnF=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnF.max().reset_index()
..
..
..
ColumnZ=df5.groupby(['patient_ID']).ColumnZ.max().reset_index()
```

I tried the following below to automate the above code but it didnt work :(

```
indexList=[ColumnA, ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE ]

def testfunc1():
    for var1 in (indexList):
        var1=df5.groupby(['audience_member_id']).var1.max().reset_index()
```

Any helpful tips to accomplish this automation would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: for this, you can try to debug your own by printing the each ```var1``` in the loop, so you can see what's going on. Also, post the error message, too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cols = ['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', ...]
df5.groupby('patient_ID')[cols].max().reset_index()
```

Comment: This didnt work, the error is "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"...

Comment: would you please print the head of your dataframe